# What is the closed form for this norm $\|Z\|=\sup_{\|u\|=1,\|v\|=1} u^TZv$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I read a paper, which has the equation above $\|Z\|=\sup_{\|u\|=1,\|v\|=1} u^TZv$. Is this a well known norm and what is the closed form for this norm. Also what does this norm describe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the vector norm are Euclidean, then this is the spectral norm, the operator norm to the Euclidean vector norm. Often called $2$-norm. Not to confuse with the Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the euclidian norm, for $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\setminus \{0\}$ we have 
\begin{gather}
\sup_{\|v\|=1}  \|Zv\|=\sup_{\|v\|=1,Zv\neq0} \frac{\|Zv\|^2}{\|Zv\|}=
\sup_{\|v\|=1,Zv\neq0} (\frac{Zv}{\|Zv\|})^{\top} (Zv)\\
\leq \sup_{\|u|=1,\|v\|=1}u^\top (Zv)\stackrel{\mathrm{csi}}{\leq}\sup_{\|u|=1,\|v\|=1}\|u\|*\|Zv\|
=\sup_{\|v\|=1}\|Zv\|.
\end{gather}

This implies
\begin{gather}\sup_{\|u|=1,\|v\|=1}u^\top Zv=\sup_{\|v\|=1}  \|Zv\|,\end{gather}
so your given norm is the spectral norm.

Comment: Can you give me the definition of the spectral norm in math? Is it the largest singular value?

Comment: The usual definition of the spectral norm of $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is $\sup_{\|v\|\leq1}\|Zv\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm and for $n>0$ this equals $\sup_{\|v\|=1}\|Zv\|$. By using the singular value decomposition you can indeed show that the spectral norm is the largest singular value.